# How to limit select output from sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I stop using **SQL Developer** as found more convenient to use **SQL Plus** inside Emacs SQLi mode.

**SQL Developer** on selects with large amount of rows show only few rows. But **SQL Plus** tend to dump all rows that match conditions. I can put `ROWNUM <= N` but I often forget to do this.

Is there any option for **SQL Plus** to limit it output from `select` statement? I will put it to `/opt/instantclient/glogin.sql` in order to apply to each sesstion...

Comment: I don't think there is such an option.

Comment: Seems to me too. I read docs and doesn't find any related `set` command...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can. The only thing I know that sort of does that (but is slightly annoying IMO) is the `PAUSE` option which waits for you to press enter between pages. The annoying part is that it pauses before the first row... You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt when you've seen enough.

```
SQL> set pause on
SQL> set pages 10 pause 'press enter to continue'
SQL> select object_name from dba_objects;
press enter to continue

OBJECT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ICOL$
I_USER1
CON$
UNDO$
C_COBJ#
I_OBJ#
PROXY_ROLE_DATA$
press enter to continue

OBJECT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I_IND1
I_CDEF2
I_OBJ5
I_PROXY_ROLE_DATA$_1
FILE$
UET$
I_FILE#_BLOCK#
press enter to continue

I_FILE1
ERROR:
ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

15 rows selected.
```

Comment: First set the pause on. SQL> set pause on SQL> set pages 10 pause 'press enter to continue'

Comment: Thanks @emily. Wasn't necessary on the system I tried that at first, but just came upon one where it was. Edited accordingly.

Comment: The problem for me is if i press CTRL+C it exists out of sqlplus completeley